# Fibonacci in JSON Arrays using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, fibonacci

So far I tried this on success function in my AJAX:

```
$.map(t, function (e) {
    var loc = e.location;
    var prov = e.province;
    header = loc + ", " + prov;
    var data = e.data;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var dataEl = data[i];
        var accumRain = data[i].rain_value;
        var accumRainNext = data[i + 1].rain_value;
        finalAccum = parseFloat(accumRain + accumRainNext);
        accumRain = accumRainNext;
        accumRainNext = finalAccum;
        console.log(i + " " + finalAccum);
        t = dataEl.dateTimeRead;
        a.push([t, parseFloat(dataEl.rain_cum)]), o.push([t, parseFloat(dataEl.rain_value) * 4])
    }
});
```

But it returns an error that "rain_value":

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rain_value' of undefined

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattmorz/yh08xfq6/) for reference. And also I'm getting the wrong value of finalAccum. It seems that its not adding the values. Any help?

Comment: Did you try to change the for statement to be: i < data.length - 1  ?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing: data[i + 1].rain_value and it won't exists when you reach the last element of the array. You should check if i is smaller than length - 1 before that line.

Comment: OK, but I'm getting the wrong value of "finalAccum".

Comment: You could probably set accumRightNext to 0 if it doesn't match the condition mentioned on the answer. So it could be "if (i < data.length - 1) { accumRainNext = data[i + 1].rain_value } else { accumRainNext = 0 }.

Comment: In your code, i also see that you declared finalAccum as an array. And inside your function, you are assigning it a value. So, it will be overwrote on each iteration. I am not sure what you want to do with your finalAccum but if you want to add an item to an array, you should do: finalAccum.push(whatever);